# Compilar um webservice

Tags: java, web-service, eclipse, tomcat

Eu criei um WebService no eclipse utilizando java, porém como eu compilo esse WebService e coloco para funcionar sem a necessidade de instalar o Eclipse?

Obs: Utilizei tomcat como servidor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário a instalação do Tomcat, Glassfish ou o servidor de sua preferencia. Vamos falar como fazer com o Tomcat. Com seu servidor pronto para receber seu webservice é necessário que você exporte seu projeto como um arquivo war seguindo esses passos no Eclipse: Botão direito em cima do projeto, export > other > war. Com esse arquivo em mãos basta entrar no seu Manager do Tomcat, ir até a opção escrita Deploy colocar as informações do seu Webservice como path etc e selecionar o arquivo .war gerado. Após todos esses passos seu Webservice sera listado nos serviços disponiveis do Tomcat na aba manager e lá estará o link para acesso do mesmo.